# Why my push function is not working when I am inserting the value in same array

Tags: javascript

```
var myNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var Remve = [];
var i;

for(i=0;i<myNums.length;i++){
    if(myNums[i] % 3 == 0){
        Remve.push(myNums[i])
    }else{
        myNums.push(myNums[i])
    }
}

document.write(myNums);
document.write(Remve);
```

Why is my push function not working when I am inserting the value in the same array?

When I am inserting in another array it works.

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? What is the actual vs intended behaviour?

Comment: Are you aware that you're checking the new length of myNums at each iteration ? So this loop has no end. Your goal isn't clear but maybe you want `for(var i=0, i=myNums.length; i<n;i++){`

Comment: you're generating an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dissecting the relevant parts of your code:

```
// Allocate an array containing three values that will match: [3, 6, 9]
var myNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

// Get the length of myNums *every iteration*
for (i = 0; i < myNums.length; i++) {
  if (myNums[i] % 3 == 0) {
    ...
  } else {
    // Append the value to myNums if it is evenly divisible by three
    myNums.push(myNums[i])
  }
}
```

This will hit an infinite loop.

On each iteration, `myNums` will look like:

```
[_1_, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] // append 1
[1, _2_, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1] // append 2
[1, 2, _3_, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3, _4_, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2] // append 4
[1, 2, 3, 4, _5_, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 4] // append 5
... and so on
```

Once you've hit the end of the collection, every iteration will append yet another value to the very end.

You can solve this pretty easily, if you don't want to hit the appended items:

```
var myNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var Remve = [];
var i;

var l = myNums.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  if (myNums[i] % 3 == 0) {
    Remve.push(myNums[i])
  } else {
    myNums.push(myNums[i])
  }
}

document.write(myNums);
document.write(Remve);
```

By caching the length first, you won't enter the infinite loop.

You can also push the undivisible items into a different array instead of onto the end of the current one, which will solve the problem equally well.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what you meant by "not working," and I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I saw a problem. The loop was going off of the length of the array, which was changing each time the array ran after the 9th iteration, causing an infinite loop. Saving that in a static variable fixed this:

```
var myNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var Remve = [];
var i;

var myNumLength = myNums.length;

for(i=0;i<myNumLength;i++){
    if(myNums[i] % 3 == 0){
        Remve.push(myNums[i])
    }else{
        myNums.push(myNums[i])
    }
}

document.write(myNums);
document.write('<br>');
document.write(Remve);
```

Update: new code:

```
var originalNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var newNums = [];
var removedNums = [];
var i;

var myNumLength = originalNums.length;

for(i=0;i<myNumLength;i++){
    if(originalNums[i] % 3 == 0){
        removedNums.push(originalNums[i])
    }else{
        newNums.push(originalNums[i])
    }
}

document.write(newNums);
document.write('<br>');
document.write(removedNums);
```

Update again

```
var myNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var removedNums = [];
var i;

var myNumLength = myNums.length;

for(i=0;i<myNumLength;i++){
    if(myNums[i] % 3 == 0){
        removedNums.push(myNums[i]);
        myNums.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}

document.write(myNums);
document.write('<br>');
document.write(removedNums);
```

Comment: thank you james but both mynums value shows before and after

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to insert the remaining value after remove 3 6 9  in array

Comment: @user3090653 does my updated code have the expected result?

Comment: Thank you so much james but i have to do it with out taking any other array

Comment: @user3090653 okay... did it without another array... what is this for?

Answer (score 0):

A) You are constantly checking myNums.length, while inserting values into it.

B) It IS working, as you can see the same values appearing in myNums over and over again.  But this is an infinite loop.

C) Console.log(Rmve); shows that you are indeed selecting for numbers divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0):

It is running in an infinite loop. You are pushing value in a same array so the array length keeps on increasing and it will never end.

```
    var myNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var Remve = [];
var i;

for(i=0;i<myNums.length;i++){
    if(myNums[i] % 3 == 0){
        Remve.push(myNums[i])
    }else{
        myNums.push(myNums[i]) //problematic line
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is generating an infinite loop, your exit condition is never met.

Notice that `myNums.length` is constantly increased since you're adding new elements inside loop.

You should get array length before start iterating

```
var myNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var Remve = [];
var i;
var arrayLength = myNums.length; // get length BEFORE starting for loop

for(i=0; i < arrayLength; i++){
    if(myNums[i] % 3 == 0){
        Remve.push(myNums[i])
    }else{
        myNums.push(myNums[i])
    }
}

alert(myNums);
alert(Remve);
```

Comment: I am trying to insert the remaining value after remove 3 6 9 in array

Answer (score -1):

Use a separate array (myNumsArr) to store the values instead of myNums. Your current code will result in infinite loop.

```
var myNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var myNumsArr = [];
var Remve = [];
var i;

for(i=0;i<myNums.length;i++){
    if(myNums[i] % 3 == 0){
        Remve.push(myNums[i])
    }else{
        myNumsArr.push(myNums[i])
    }
}

myNums = myNums.concat(myNumsArr);
```

Comment: Why negative mark for this answer? Please explain.

Comment: Store remaining value in same array

Comment: Okay, I am sure you have got the solution by now. But, the other option is, you can concat the new array (myNumsArr) with the myNums once the for loop is complete. This way you can have visibility on what values that are not divided by 3.